# Can't find one example using the genitive strong ending of -en

Tags: grammatical-number, genitive, adjective-ending

I can't find examples (or think of one) where the genitive strong ending **-en** is used; that is, where the 1.) noun is singular and its gender is masculine or neuter, 2.) no determiner precedes the noun and 3.) the case is genitive.

An example like

> Die Hoffnungen armer Menschen bleiben oft unerfüllt. (The hopes of poor
> people often remain unfulfilled)

uses the strong **-er** ending because *Menschen* is plural. Are instances of the genitive strong attributive adjective ending **-en** rare?

Answer (score 5):

Here are some good examples, even if they feel a bit stiff:

> Die Weiße *neugefallenen* Schnees kann blenden – bringen Sie eine Sonnenbrille mit.
> Mir gefällt der Geschmack *roten* Weines.
> Der Gewinner *letzen* Jahres wurde von der Höhe der Preissumme überwältigt und gab alles innerhalb weniger Monate aus.

You can also see it in several idiomatic phrases:

> Sei guten Mutes! (Be of good cheer!)
> Allen Ernstes (In all seriousness)
> [etw.] gleichen/selben Namens ([something] of the same name)
> Letzten Endes (in the end/after all)
> Schweren Herzens (with a heavy heart)

Comment: @guidot Woops, was typing fast, thank you :)

Comment: One with neuter I have from my notes is *Das Aroma frischen Heus ist entspannend.* I think the one with *rot* and *Wein*, which I admit is very tempting, is a bit awkward since normally you'd merge them into *Rotwein*. These are unusual cases though and I've seen at least one grammar site on-line get them wrong. In every other case the strong inflection matches the definite article, so it seems very odd to have these random seeming exceptions that would rarely come up.

Comment: @RDBury, Yes, I agree, the example with *rot* and *Wein* is awkward, perhaps I could have used something else. *Mir gefällt der Geschmack italienischen Weines*? In any case, most of these will examples are not quite *umgangssprachlich*

Comment: @Numeri says Reinstate Monica
Thanks so much!

Comment: @RDBury According to the book German in Review, since you would only use the -en genitive ending on singular masculine or neuter nouns when they don't already have a der-word--and that's a fairly uncommon construction--it recommends instead learning idioms that use the construction, rather than learning is as a variation on basic grammatical structure.

Comment: @kurt krueckeberg: That might be for the best. Another explanation is that adjectives behave like weak nouns rather than articles, at least in some cases. I don't know the history of why adjective declination is the way it is now, but I'm guessing it seemed very logical and natural in Proto-Germanic.